# i3wm: how to configure touchpad?

Tags: i3

I use `debian` and `i3wm`.

How to configure touchpad? I mean "cleck-on-tap", vertical scrolling via right touchpad side.

Comment: For reference: [a very simple tutorial](https://cravencode.com/post/essentials/enable-tap-to-click-in-i3wm/) & [a libinput wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput) & [libinput documentation](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is with **synclient**.

Use:

```
synclient -l
```

to list all options and their current settings and then you can use:

```
synclient var1=value1 [var2=value2] ...
```

to change the different options.

To make changes permanent you can either create a script and run it on i3 logon or edit the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d (if you don't have it copy it from /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf ).
In /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d you should write your settings under:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "touchpad"
Driver "synaptics"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
```

In the form:

```
Option "var1" "value1"
...
```

For tap-click and vertical scroll on right you should add:

```
Option "TapButton1" "1"
Option "VertEdgeScroll" "0"
```

You can also take a look at arch linux wiki page about [Touchpad_Synaptics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics)

If you want more gestures take a look at [touchegg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/touchegg)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I added `exec --no-startup-id synclient VertEdgeScroll=1 TapButton1=1 TapButton2=1 TapButton3=1` to `i3wm` config and it should work.

Answer (score 13):

Since [Touchpad Synaptics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics) is no longer actively updated you can use [libinput](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput) instead.

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-touchpad.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "libinput"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
    Option "ScrollMethod" "edge"
EndSection
```

[Here](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/libinput.4) are all options listed.

Comment: it's deprecated, true, but libinput has nowhere near the amount of options synaptics has.

Comment: This works on Debian 10. Althought the file is in: /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf. https://wiki.debian.org/LibinputTouchpad